# c# how to manage wcf service proxy lifecycle on client side?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, client

I have written a WCF service with some regular functionality (add user, remove, search, update...). The implementation of this functionality is in entity framework (with sql DB).

Now I want to use it in the client side.
And I have some basic questions:

1. I have many calls to the WCF methods in the client side - should I try catch every time each call?
2. Every time I want to call a method, for example AddUser(User user), I need to make an instance of my service, like that:

   ```
   WcfService client = new WcfService();
   client.AddUser(user);
   ```

   And in another place I write:

   ```
   WcfService client = new WcfService(); //Again making a new instance...
   client.UpdateUser(user);
   ```

Should I make one instance for all the application for my wcf service?
Or every time to make a new instance before I call to a method? (as in my example above).

Thanks very much !

Comment: Creating multiple instances is fine, but close connection and dispose them once you're done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(i)You can make an instance one time for a service, and use the same client whenever you need to make a method call. if you are aborting or closing the connection then you need to create each time.

(ii)It is better if you use try catch methods in each methods, so it will be easy to close the connection and identify the exceptions.

Comment: If I try catch it, then for each call I need to catch Timeout and Endpoint Exceptions and I need also to handle entire FaultExceptions, that contains wcf errors, and also validations errors... It becomes very big, each method call has at least 3 catches, isn't this too much? It makes each method to be large...

Answer (score 6):

In many cases, you want to reuse the same client proxy, as this connection method yields the best performance. Reusing the same proxy can be particularly beneficial if you use security features, which have a high initial security negotiation cost. Note: you surely need to check the state of the client proxy before using.

In the event that reusing the same client proxy is not an option, then consider using a ChannelFactory proxy that uses caching.

The following link provides a good explanation along with best practice recommendations:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx